# C++ Pointer Issue

Tags: c++, pointers

`_stuckVertices` is an array of pointers and I would like to update one index of that array without using `_stuckVertices[ (row * _cols) + column ]` 3 times.  The reason it is an array of pointers is because the vast majority of the time the pointer will be NULL.  The following code works but I need to dereference a each time I use it:

```
void Cloth::stickPoint(int column, int row)
{
    Anchor **a = &_stuckVertices[ (row * _cols) + column ];
    if (!*a)
        *a = new Anchor(this, column, row);
    (*a)->stick();
}
```

I originally had it written like this, but the _stuckVertices pointer doesn't get updated:

```
void Cloth::stickPoint(int column, int row)

    {
        Anchor *a = _stuckVertices[ (row * _cols) + column ];
        if (!a)
            a = new Anchor(this, column, row);
        a->stick();
    }
```

Is there a way to write `Anchor *a = _stuckVertices[ index ]` so that `a` is like an alias into the array that I can update, or is something like the first piece of code how I should do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References are what you are looking for - they are aliases:

```
Anchor*& a = _stuckVertices[ (row * _cols) + column ];
if (!a)
    a = new Anchor(this, column, row);
a->stick();
```

Comment: You answer another one of my questions, thanks :)  In C would using ** and dereferencing everywhere be the only option?

Comment: *Second try, i have to learn to read ;)* Yes, sadly in C there are no real aliases.

Comment: You _could_ use a macro in C,
`#define a (_stuckVertices[ (row * _cols) + colnum ])`, you'd just need to be careful with it (well you have to be careful with the reference too, but for slightly different reasons, and in different ways).

Answer (score -1):

> _stuckVertices is an array of pointers

What do you mean by this? Did oyu created it like this:
Anchor *_stuckVertices = new Anchor[Number];
or like this:
Anchor *_stuckVertices[Number]={0};
?

In first case you should be able to do this:

```
Anchor *a = _stuckVertices +((row * _cols) + column);
a->stick();
```

In second case:

```
Anchor *a = _stuckVertices[((row * _cols) + column)];
a->stick();
```

And just a hint, (row * _cols) + column could be bigger then array-length 
You should at least add an assertion before accessing _stuckVertices e.g.:

```
#include <cassert>
assert (sizeof(_stuckVertices)/sizeof(_stuckVertices[0]) > ((row * _cols) + column) );
```

Regards,
Valentin Heinitz

Comment: You ignore the assigment of the new instance in both cases, which is the real problem.